# Useful King's Bounty units / unit combinations

Tags: kings-bounty-the-legend

The `King's Bounty - The Legend` and `King's Bounty - Armored Princess` games have an impressive amount of different creatures to use. I tried switching creatures often, but the morale system really discourages true diversity in army builds, and so there are many different units I have not even tried.

I would like to know what units / unit combination have been proven successful for other players in either of these great games, so I'll have a chance to try them out next time :) I'm especially interested in success stories with creatures that appear only mildly useful on first glance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Most powerful units

I tried a great number of different units' combinations. I am now at the very end of the game, and the units I have found useful for the entire game (provided you get them early) are **Inquisitors** and **Skeleton Archers**.

**Inquisitors** because:

- Cheap
- Resurrection
- Magic ranged damage (holy no less, so extra damage to undead... make great ghost killers)
- A bless spell that gives your hero extra rage!

How could you not like that?

**Skeleton Archer**; anyone who has used these with dragon arrow on them knows why they are useful:

- Dirt cheap
- Decent base damage considering the low leadership cost
- Two bonus damage specials that are both excellent
- They have the largest bonus from dragon arrow boost.
- You can make HUGE stacks of them.  I'm currently running with 2000 of them.
  with dragon arrows cast on them, they easily can take out a stack of 15 black dragons in a single shot. No kidding.
- They're immune to mind spells.
- You can find them in graves, and almost any cemetary.

### Other very good units

If you have the ring of "Shedominance" (you'll know it when you get it),
fairy power is teh awesome. A stack of 3000 **Blessed Sprites** or **Lake Fairies** are gonna do around 25K on a crit! I'm not kidding. Sprites do more base damage, but Lake Fairies have better crit chance, and are not weak against fire, and can occasionally weaken foes, so highly recommend Lake Fairies for going up against things that use fire.

**Dryads** are also great for similar reasons, though they do about half the damage since the stacks are less than half as big. Moreover, Dryads are also a must bring because:

- They can put to sleep ALL enemy units level 3 or lower that are not immune to mind spells.  this just gets better and better as the game goes along.
- They can summon huge stacks of low level plants to act as fodder for any number do things

Once you start getting access to **Dragons** (probably the earlier will be in the *Dwarven Lands*):

- **Green ones** are great for sucking up mana for you.
- **Red ones** have a fantastic special attack.
- **Bone Dragons** also have a good attack, but cannot be healed or rezzed by inquisitors or you.
- **Black ones** are the toughest, but you can't cast spells like phantom, or slayer, or bless on them.

So if you have to choose... I'd go with taking along both a Green and Red stack, and ignoring the others.

Those are the primary units I used for most of the game.

### Other excellent units

**Shamans**: Great magic attack at range, easy to get early, decent tanks, and can cast totems that work as distractions. Very very useful in the islands and dwarf areas.

**Evil Beholders**: Fantastic magic ranged attack that can put low level enemies to sleep, plus can charm units for a turn, which is very very useful for much of the game.  If you find them early... grab them! They get a bit less useful once you start facing off against higher level opponents on a regular basis, but they are great for the first half of the game at least.

**Horsemen**: Despite what some might say, you CAN get these units on day 1 of your adventure, and they are well worth the price. Find the horse/knight tent a little ways away from where you start the game. Run past the stack guarding it to the clearing next to the tent. When the enemy army goes back to the front of the tent... CAREFULLY move along the side of the tent, until you are *just* level with the guide wire at the front of the tent. From there, you should be able to click on the purchase unit button without alerting the guards. When done, run back past the guards again. Having horsies early on is very very useful.. a good solid unit you can use for the entire game if you like.

Answer (score 3):

Kings Bounty is basically the same as Heroes of Might and Magic and other similar hexbased tactical battle games. They all borrowed heavily from each other. So the strategies are generally the same. Obviously you want to protect your long range units (mages and archers) and use them to pick off enemy stacks before they become decimated themselves by enemy fire. Your infantry/cavalry units should be used to either block up the ground if your enemies are rushers, or charge in close to enemy ranged units so that they are ineffective. As far as morale bonuses go, try and avoid mixing different race types. Some units are uneffected by morale but most gain or lose bonuses based on what other units are in the same army. While it is handy for example to have a stack of Skeletons to act as fodder they cost more than they give if you pair them up with humans.

Answer (score 2):

I like using Cursed Ghost (50% resist physical ) with the spell Haste. Just put them in the midst of the enemy and use the Archmage Shield skill (another 50% resist physical ). It virtually takes 25% damage and their live drain skills to boost! I usually have more ghost aftermath,

Answer (score 2):

I combined my army acording to wives and items i had. Very good combinatiom is mirabella (+100% attack) or rina (+1 speed) with pirate flag, boots and pirate sword of some kind. Units of choice are all robbers and pirates as they all will benefit from all items and wife bonuses. There are 2 robber type units and 2 pirate, the fifth creature should be archmage/shaman/inquisitor for support and abilities or even archers if playing warrior. most usefull spell if you are not playing mage is resurrection.

Answer (score 1):

Well "best" army combination always depends on where are you going (hell have fire resist creatures, other places are full of undead, etc.), what kind of hero you got (I think a warrior needs a more diverse army, but with mage I like a tanky army more, they take the damage and I cast the spells) and what kind of creatures are available atm. My personal favourites are:

- Human: Horseman and Knight are neat, but if I can switch them off for something I like more I won't hesitate to do so. Inquisitors on the other hand are REALLY good, resurrection, holy anger with blessing and some free rage for your hero, and holy damage against undead units.
- Dwarf: Alchemist (It has a very good set of skills, it has poison, fire and holy damage, and a good close range damage as well, also decent health) and Giant (until dragons I use them, they are heavily tanky and that jump is pretty neat against non flying units) and cannoner for that neat triple shot.
- Elves: Their archers are good, but I don't really like elf units. They aren't bad, but I don't like them.
- Orcs: Shaman is a very, VERY good thing to have in your army, dancing axes can heal your team, and totems can be useful too. The others can be good too, but personally I only like the shaman.
- undead: pretty neat especially if you build on them with talents too, skeleton archers, ghosts, vampires, black knight, necromancer and the bone dragon are all great.
- Demons: Well I usually go for Demon, Demoness, and Archdemon, but at this point of the game there will be a lot of enemies, that are immune or resistant to fire damage (other demons and dragons), so they can be useless unless you have some leftover armies somewhere else.
- Other kind: I like the bears, especially ancient bears, Evil beholder is a good thing to have, cyclops could be good, but to be honest, they are not that good later on the game, but still. Dragons are great too to have, but again, after you can acquire them, you mostly fight against armies of dragons and demons, and fire is quite ineffective against them (except for green dragons, who have physical damage).

For late game I would say go for tanky units, Mostly you fight dragons, so knights are essential, also green dragons can be neat too with physical damage and mana restoration. I usually take shamans too, dropping down totems to distract the enemy can be useful, and the dancing axes are pretty good to have. Also I usually take either other kind of dragons, or undeads (if I talented them), like bone dragons and Black knight.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer undead build.
It works best with warrior or mage (it looks bad, if paladin has undead army :D). Undead commander (skill in a might tree, a must have in this build, of course). Vampire crown, vampire ring and vampire sword (stuff like that), these items make vampire TOTALLY OP. Morale increased each time on cemetery.

**Ancient vampires:** One of the best troops in the game. they are fast and powerful. They cost quite a lot but they have life draining ability, so you can get them back in battle (no need to re-buy them after battle). Since they can raise from the dead each time you attack enemy (life draining), you can use them as tanks as well. No retaliation too.

**Vampires:** Cheaper and less powerful version of ancient vampires, but you can have more of them.

**Necromancers:** One of the best again. Good damage, magic lock, raise dead (essential!!!), a totally must have.

**Cursed ghosts:** Life draining again, all units with life draining are overpowering imo. Also quite powerful and not too expensive.

**Skeleton archers:** Amazing damage output, but bad if you play no loss, because they have only about 10 health.

OR

**Black knights:** best tank unit in  game, but vampires do everything, I only use them to clean the battlefield in the end.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't learned much about the tactics and the way to win in this game yet, but I have found that certain creatures have an unreasonable advantage when attacking one specific kind of other creatures. For example the Horde (humans with pitchforks) are nigh useless, except against certain creatures, where it seems unreasonably effective, such as anything that is insect or animal-like.

I have not found any strategy to building your army other than the obvious tactics game basics; you have your ranged attacks (those who can hurl magic or arrows across the playing field) and those who must be beside what they want to attack.  I think winning may be more to do with maximizing your attack bonuses by which troop you send against what opposing type of troop.

Answer (score 0):

I really liked Swordsmen, Archers, Ancient bears, Barbarians, and Guardsmen, but I like to play with the Warrior character because spirits of rage are really good with him and he can have a lot of units; that's my way of playing. Try it; I beat the game in sixteen days and was in the top five in the records.

Answer (score 0):

I've played over 50 hours of "the legend" and I'm now stuck. I don't have enough gold to buy new units and I can't find any monster stacks easier than "very hard". I searched the tubes a lot for answers and it seems that what I really overlooked is the spell resurection with an all human crew.

Basically, the trick is to have resurrection at a high level and "magic [something]" that allows you to regen mana when your creature gets hit. This will allow you to raise your army back on track whenever you get hit.

The units themselves are not that important, but your gold is like your total hp that you carry through the game. Even if you carry misfitted units but they don't die when you fight, you're all good

Comment: "magic spring" ~~

Answer (score -2):

royal grifins knights paladins unicorns and inquisitors vs undead and level 3 elfs ranged.

Comment: Why is this a good unit combination.  Just telling us what you use is a good start, but you really need to add why for a good answer.